# How can I set limit of maximum number of lines allowed per file to 5000 lines in VS code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a requirement where I need to set the maximum number of lines allowed per file to 5000 lines only in VS Code editor. If any user tries to press enter key on line number 5000, they won't be allowed to enter any characters further.

Comment: Seems fragile. If this was a setting, what if they override it? If a plugin, they could disable or uninstall. And finally, they could just open in another editor and make the change. What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Well what you are saying is absolutely true, but that is what my requirement is. I have written a git pre-commit hook which would not allow to push the code to my repository if it reaches 5001 lines but still it has got limitations like user can pass no verify and escape from it. My requirement is to keep the length of my code not exceed 5000 lines in any case.

Comment: What's the codebase that you are dealing with? Is it javascript/typescript/node related?

Comment: It is reactjs...

Comment: so if your file reaches 5000 lines you end with an `#include`

Comment: Yes, need to import file in case if it exceeds 5000 lines.